# Module PyEMD is not found

Tags: python, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwi4K.png)

I have already install pyemd but it still found error

I try to use CEEMDAN to extract IMFs of eight time series of "M01AB", "M01AE", "N02BA", "N02BE", "N05B", "N05C", "R03", "R06" from data file salesdaily

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me

```
pip install pyemd
pip install EMD-signal
```

then find the `pyemd` package in `Lib\site-packages` and rename it into `PyEMD`

In your python, import the package using

```
from PyEMD.CEEMDAN import CEEMDAN
```

Comment: As referenced in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyemd/) (Python Packaging Index), simply use the module name without the uppercase letters. Just this: `import pyemd`. It's that simple, there's no need to rename the module.

Comment: It's right. But I think this answer is still valid, since it works. I didn't test it.